# vmware workstation player - run VM entirely out of RAM (do not allow swap space to be used)

Tags: memory, virtualization, vmware, swap

As the title states I am running into an issue with vmware workstation player (version 12).

**HOST OS** - Elementary 0.4

**GUEST OS** - Any, in this case rhel7

**Swap Space** - None (there's a dumb reason that is probably not important here)

I remember a long time ago I'd set some configs manually that forced vmware workstation player to run the VM entirely using RAM and *not* allow the usage of swap space. Currently all of my VM's are painfully slow and it appears like they're trying to use the negligible swapspace that kind of exists.

Does anyone know where the config file and line-to-add/edit would be to force "player" to use only RAM? I know this is a nice feature with a graphical menu in Vmware Workstation, but I'm not able to upgrade at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Modifying `/etc/vmware/config` on Linux (or `%ProgramData%\VMware Workstation\config.ini` on Windows) and setting `prefvmx.minVmMemPct = "100"` corresponds to the "Fit all virtual machine memory into reserved host RAM" option in VMware Workstation.

Setting it to `"50"` corresponds to "Allow some virtual machine memory to be swapped".

Setting it to `"25"` corresponds to "Allow most virtual machine memory to be swapped".

Comment: THIS is what i was looking for but i'm hosting it on a linux machine - do you think that config.ini might have another name?

Comment: to answer my own question above i found it with the find command in `/etc/vmware/config`

Comment: @driedupsharpie Oops!  I didn't noticed that you were using a Linux host OS.  Yes, that is the correct file.  I've updated my answer, so feel free to accept it. =)